# Неправильное форматирование больших чисел: английский разделитель тысяч и дробной части, дефис вместо минуса

Tags: дефект, локализация

Повторно воспользуюсь этой картинкой:

[image]

1. Репутация отформатирована как **20,100** (с запятой).

   - Должно быть **20 100** (с неразрывным пробелом).
2. Изменение репутации отформатировано как **-19240** (с дефисом и без разделителя тысяч).

   - Должно быть **−19 240** (с символом минуса и неразрывным пробелом).
3. Влияние отформатировано как **~323k** (с тильдой и английским "k").

   - Должно быть **≈323 тыс.** (с символом примерного равенства, русским "тыс." и неразрывным пробелом).
   - Вариант: **≈323 т.** (с символом примерного равенства, русским "т." и неразрывным пробелом). Нежелательно: места достаточно, можно спутать с тоннами.
4. Положение в топе отформатировано как **0.92%** (с точкой и без пробела).

   - Должно быть **0,92 %** (с запятой и узким неразрывным пробелом).
   - Вариант: **0,92%** (с запятой и без пробела).

Аналогичные проблемы наблюдаются со всеми остальными числами.

Есть ещё сомнительное **20.1k** на плашках участников, но для начала надо разобраться с простыми случаями.

Comment: С тоннами спутать нельзя, потому что после тонн точка не ставится :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov В народе очень слабое понимание, когда точки ставятся, а когда нет, поэтому я бы не полагался на грамотность.

Answer (score 5):

Недавно был [изменён формат отображения кол-ва просмотров](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350339/3240681) и из ответа чётко можно понять, что национальные стандарты не будут (пока) применяться на сайтах SE.

Хотя, казалось бы, не так сложно добавить переменные, задающие разделитель/знак/суффикс... и предоставить возможность их локализации в Transifex.

Пока даже [с датами не могут разобраться](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290392/339911), хотя там уже имеется некий базис для этого.

Наличие точки вместо запятой в значении с суффиксом, типа `20.1k`, я думаю, можно объяснить тем, что символ разделителя разрядов целого числа должен отличаться от разделителя целой и дробной части.

Comment: Печаль. Поставил плюсик на посте на MSE.

Comment: Хочу `к`, а не `k` =/

Answer (score 1):

Программисты любят точки. Во всех языках программирования используются точки. На любом калькуляторе стоят точки. Я **не хочу** видеть запятую в роли разделителя дробной части.

Так же я не хочу видеть типографский минус вместо дефиса, поскольку в случае копирования числа с ним я получу syntax error, а не отрицательное число.

Суффиксы `K`, `M` и подобные вполне интернациональные - нет смысла с ними что-то делать.

Единственное, с чем я согласен из всех предложений - заменить запятую на неразрывный пробел. На мой взгляд, числа так смотрятся лучше.

Кстати, есть локали, в к которых используется такая комбинация. А у меня на компьютерах в настройках везде выставлены точка и пробел.

Comment: Наличие дефиса-минуса при копировании репутации (зачем?!) вам не поможет, если число с запятыми: "-19,240". Языки программирования любят не английское форматирование чисел, а своё особенное. / У меня на компе британская локаль с аналогичными модификациями (ещё правлю на ISO-шную дату).

Comment: @Squidward, запятую-то (или пробел) я визуально увижу и удалю. А вот этот минус - нет. А по поводу пробелов - вроде VB.NET уже их поддерживает? Впрочем, копипаст репутации в VB.NET-код - это что-то маловероятное. Скорее там будет js-консоль.

Comment: Минус вам среда разработки подсветит. И таки копировать ни одно из чисел из гуя в среду разработки вам никогда не понадобится.

Comment: Кто мне что подсветит? Если я начну что-то в консоли браузера шаманить? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz6J3.png - если там непосредственно копипаст. А скорее там будет `+$(smth).text().replace(/ /g, '')` с красивым NaN'ом в результате. И я уже что-то такое делал на страницах профиля, так что не надо говорить, что не понадобится.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, а вот не надо вытаскивать модельную информацию у представления. Воспользуйтесь официальным API. Для представления быть удобным для автоматического разбора — non-goal.