# "Для проверки предложенных правок требуется минимум 2k балла репутации."

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Строка взята с [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) страницы.

Бросилось в глаза, что аналогичные сообщения используют слово "баллов" вместо "балла".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сравните с:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю заменить на "баллов", поскольку:

1. Эта форма используется и в остальных случаях
2. Читается как "две тысячи баллов", а не "две тысячи балла".

Comment: да и 2k,3k тоже надо заменить на русский

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не уверен. На сайте повсеместно можно увидеть именно k-шные постфиксы к репутации. Хотя, с другой стороны, это когда ее очень много. А 2000 и 3000 - числа 4-х значные, так что, может, в этом и есть смысл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод исправлен для согласования с имеющимися. Будет на сайте после подкачки transifex и пересборки движка.

Изменить «2к» на «2000» здесь не представляется возможным средствами транзифекс, так как это значение подставляется в виде готовой строки движком. Предложение изменить запись вида «2к», но на «2 тыс.», а не «2000» было предложено ранее: [Неправильное форматирование больших чисел: английский разделитель тысяч и дробной части, дефис вместо минуса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5623/176217)