# А нельзя ли локализовать формат вывода репутации?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

На момент создание вопроса у меня 1001 балл репутации на ruSO. Отображается это кол-во как

> 1,001

Что не соответствует "культуре" RU-ru. Я бы не создавал такой вопрос, но как-то для ruSO и его Меты, особенно последние года два характерна безудержная локализация. А тут на этом фоне, такое не привычное для русскоязычных интерфейсов представление числа...

И так. Возможно ли преобразовать вывод баллов к принятому в русскоязычных странах способу форматирования чисел? Нужно ли?

Comment: Не знаю возможно ли. Но, если возможно, то нужно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неправильное форматирование больших чисел: английский разделитель тысяч и дробной части, дефис вместо минуса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5623/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%87-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d

Comment: О ... ссылка криво вставилась автоматическая.

Comment: @alexolut ограничение на длину. Вот и повод завести новый баг)

Comment: [Ссылка на дубль](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5623)

Comment: @alexolut, удалить или дождаться, когда закроете?

Comment: Дубликаты обычно не удаляются - это дополнительная точка доступа к информации. А закрывается вопрос для того, чтобы ответы были в одном месте.