# Отсутствие перевода буковки "m"

Tags: дефект, локализация

Читал я тут <strike>какую-то бурду</strike> [важные изменения сайта](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) и проверял их на аккаунте @Qwertiy (ибо у него много всего, на чем можно увидеть изменения).

Помню недавно я где-то говорил, что буковки типа `k`, обозначающие "тысяча", переводить не надо, так как к ним все итак привыкли. Так вот я поменял свое мнение, увидев это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буковка `m` самым ужаснейшим образом примостилась к русским словам (на `reached` внимания не обращаем. Это уже [было](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11645/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-reached-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5)).

А вот мой профиль с той самой буквой "k"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю переводы:
`k` - `тыс.`
`m` - `млн`

Насчет точки можно поспорить.

> Конечно же, я не уверен, что это вообще можно перевести.

Comment: Да, кстати, учитывая, что разработчики сначала выпустили обнову, а потом решили ее пообсуждать, думаю, что назад они ее уже не окатят. Даже не смотря на 139 минусов на посте об этой самой обнове. Поэтому ее можно спокойно локализовывать

Comment: _«Насчет точки можно поспорить.»_ - можно, но не нужно)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неправильное форматирование больших чисел: английский разделитель тысяч и дробной части, дефис вместо минуса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5623/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Я считаю, что он не является дубликатом. В вопросе, который вы предлагаете дубликатом, обсуждается а) постановка точки или запятой как разделительного знака дробной части, б) запятой, или неразрывного пробела, или отсутствие знака как разделительного знака больших чисел, в) (возможно именно на это вы намекаете) обозначения тысяч *(и только тысяч, миллионы не затронуты)*, через `т.` или  `тыс.` и другое. Дело в том, что тот пост обсуждает предыдущую версию сайта, до обновления. Более того, там говорится про целую страницу. Я веду речь про одну-единтвенную...

Comment: ... английскую букву посреди кучи русского текста в блоке профиля. Тот вопрос слишком общий и затрагивает аж 7 **(СЕМЬ!)** символов. Я же предлагаю заменить лишь 2: `k` и `m`. И помимо всего прочего: тот вопрос уже не имеет никакой силы, так как версия, к которой он апелирует, была изменена. Вряд ли остались те строки, какие в новой версии. Плюс интерфейс полностью перекрутили, и этот вопрос нужно обсуждать заново.

Comment: @МаксимФисман дубликатами как раз и закрывают менее общие вопросы на более общие. Менять суффикс в отдельно взятом блоке, нарушая консистентность с другими страницами это очень странно. Версия (дизайн) сайта, как мне кажется, вообще не играет роли в данном случае.

Answer (score -2):

Я бы оставил K и M, но только не строчные, а заглавные.

Comment: Если М заглавная, то уже не важно, английская она или русская. Возможно "М" лучше, чем "млн". Хотя, насколько я знаю, общепринятое именно "млн". А что касается "К"... Я **ни разу в жизни** не видел (или просто не помню), чтобы тысячи обозначали именно заглавной К. Иронично, что вы первый прокомментировали это :)

Comment: @МаксимФисман, я всегда обозначаю тысячи заглавной К.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вы, простите, кто? :) Вообще, по правилам СИ, в русском для кило- используется именно маленькая к, см.: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%98#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: @АндрейNOP, во-первых, правила СИ относятся именно к физическим величинам, когда приставка ставится непосредственно перед сокращённым обозначением единицы измерения. Здесь ничего подобного нет. Ну и строчная m в системе СИ обозначает милли, а не мега. Во-вторых, в программировании суффикс типа принято обозначать заглавной буквой, а не строчной. А ещё килобайты (двоичные) обозначаются всегда заглавной КБ и KB. Так что не надо смешивать физику с русским языком (впрочем, в нём вроде тоже подходящего правила нет, как и для всяких "10+"), а надо делать красиво и понятно.

Comment: Что тогда вообще эта k обозначает? В английском в слове thousand вообще такой буквы нет. В общем большая К вообще мимо, я считаю, либо мы просто сокращаем слова как положено (тыс.), либо используем распространенные обозначения для десятичных приставок (маленькая к). А что касается КБ — это тоже не правильно, я считаю. За океаном вон вообще имперские единицы используются, это же не значит, что и нам из надо тащить :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, KB в килобайте официально расшифровывают в kibibyte.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, посмотрел, как авторы видео на ютьюбе пишут сумму 10К - у большинства буква заглавная.

Comment: @Qwerty А по-моему нет определенного определения насчет килобайта и кибибайта. Там что-то типа кБ — это килобайт, кроме тех случаев, когда требуется явно указать, что это кибибайт. Но я не настаиваю на правоте. в любом случае, это неважно потому что тут даже близко не килобайты. Единственное что еще хочу добавить: вариант с маленькой к и большой М мне кажется наихудшим. Это (лично мне кажется) странно.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, так я предлагал обе заглавные.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, я знаю. Вы просто сказали, что кило (тысяча) - `k`, а мега (миллион) - `M`, а `m` - вообще милли.  Я просто высказал мнение по вопросу "маленькая k, большая M". Возможно, не стоило адресовывать его конкретно вам.